# Notify Email on Google cloud instance deletion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

While deleting a GCP instance by using python googleapiclient, how can i notify people by sending a mail. 
Is there a way in GCP itself to send outgoing mails in case of instance deletion ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create [log based metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/) filtering the delete operation and [set the Stackdriver alert policy](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/charts-and-alerts#creating_a_simple_alerting_policy_on_a_counter_metric) based on the created log based metric.

[image: Log based metric]

As test, I created log based metric using the stackdriver filter:
resource.type="gce_instance" 
jsonPayload.event_subtype="compute.instances.delete" jsonPayload.event_type="GCE_API_CALL"

Then create an alert policy based on this metric with the configuration as per attached screenshot. [image: Stackdriver alert policy]

I deleted one of the instances in my project and received alert on the email set on the stackdriver alert policy.

Currently, there is no other way to get email notification on such operations, feel free to submit a feature request on the [GCP issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)